# Placing circles generated in css side by side without use of table in markdown file

Tags: css, responsive-design, markdown, geometry

I am drawing some circles using css. Here is how I do it:

```
circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

and here is how I use it in a markdown file:

```
<circle>Text</circle>
```

I want to place a number of these circles side-by-side with a little space between them, not on top of each other. I know I can use table and put them on a table, but the issue is that if the website is responsive then the circles will stay in a table row, for example with 3 circles in each row,  and it will look very bad on mobile devices. I can put actual images, for example, .png files, side by side without a table and on mobile devices, the images will wrap around and everything looks good. Is there a way to do the same thing when I draw circles using css?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This :**

```css
circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

```html
<circle>Text</circle>
<circle>Text</circle>
<circle>Text</circle>
```

Comment: You are Welcome!

Answer (score 3):

`<circle>` is actually an SVG element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/circle

So you should be using a `div` and then to keep the `divs` inline just use `display: inline-block;`

```css
div {
    background: #f00;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
<div>Text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `div` instead of `circle` (I think circle is only for an inline svg) and set `display` to `inline-block`.

```
div.circle {
    display:inline-block;
    background: #f00;
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border-radius: 50%;
}


<div class="circle"></div>
```