# CSS: adding an image to a circle with text

Tags: css, text, background-image

I would like to add an image to a circle that is created by CSS and has text inside. I know how to create a circle with text, for example, [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44299221/placing-circles-generated-in-css-side-by-side-without-use-of-table-in-markdown-f) StackOverflow question and answer shows how to do it. Here is the `circle` definition in css:

```
circle {
    background: #f00;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 100px;
    margin-right:5px;
}
```

and here is what I will have in html:

```
<circle>THIS IS THE TEXT</circle>
```

Now I want to be able to add a background image to the circle and if possible add an `opacity` of 0.5. So basically I want an image with a shape of circle and text on top of it. Here is an example:

[image]

The "THIS IS THE TEXT" is the text that can be written in the html code on top of the image.

How can this be done?

Comment: should the whole circle with text be opacity? Also `circle` is actually a SVG element. If you want to this kind of thing you should use any other html element, like div.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not hard to find how to do a circle with text. The `<circle>` is used for SVG, so it's not what you want here. Use a plain `<div>` instead. The solution here gives the background image a opacity.

```css
body {
  background-color: #121212;
}

.circle {
  position: relative;
  height: 300px;
  width: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.circle:hover:after {
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.circle:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background-image: url(https://buyersguide.caranddriver.com/media/assets/submodel/280_8204.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  z-index: -1;
  opacity: 1;
  transition: opacity 300ms;
}

.circle__text {
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="circle">
  <span class="circle__text">random text</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Is it possible to change the opacity of just the image when hovering over the image?

Comment: @TJ1 is this what you are looking for?

Comment: yes I want what also to be able to change opacity when hovering. But just opacity of the image not the text.

Answer (score 2):

if you want an alternate solution here is what i use

```css
.story_shape {
    width: 15rem; 
    height: 15rem; 
    -webkit-shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    shape-outside: circle(50% at 50% 50%);
    clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%); 
    position: relative; 
}

 .story_img {
    height: 100%;
    transform: translateX(-4rem);  
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
 }
 
 .story_caption {
    position: absolute; 
    top: 50%; 
    left: 50%; 
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%); 
    color: white; 
    text-transform: uppercase; 
    font-size: 1.7rem; 
    text-align: center;  
    backface-visibility: hidden; 
 }
```

```html
 <figure class="story_shape">
    <img src="https://orig00.deviantart.net/6afd/f/2015/182/4/f/croatia_nature_pack___sample__1___proref_org_by_proref-d8zgqmh.jpg" alt="person on a tour" class="story_img">
    <figcaption class="story_caption">mary smith</figcaption>
</figure>
```